# XMPP rspauth token should contain what in a DIGEST-MD5 auth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmpp, md5, sasl

Background: I'm fiddling with a XMPP server that doesn't work.

So the documentation on this particular response token called `rspauth` is not very well documented anywhere really. Some appear to just skip it and go for a static string looking like this:

```
cnNwYXV0aD1lYTQwZjYwMzM1YzQyN2I1NTI3Yjg0ZGJhYmNkZmZmZA==
```

Which b64decodes to:

```
rspauth=ea40f60335c427b5527b84dbabcdfffd
```

However at the last stages of the `MD5-DIGEST` authentication, supposedly I should be sending the following:

```
<challenge xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
   cnNwYXV0aD1lYTQwZjYwMzM1YzQyN2I1NTI3Yjg0ZGJhYmNkZmZmZA==
</challenge>
```

Again, I'm not sure why everyone everywhere in every bug report uses this static string. But any XMPP client will respond with:

```
jabber: Error is -10 : SASL(-10): server failed mutual authentication step: DIGEST-MD5: This server wants us to believe that he knows shared secret
```

I try to follow the RFC's as close as I can, and [this is what the RFC says](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2342.txt) about `rspauth=`:

> The server receives and validates the "digest-response". The server
>   checks that the nonce-count is "00000001". If it supports subsequent
>   authentication (see section 2.2), it saves the value of the nonce and 
>   the nonce-count. It sends a message formatted as follows:
>
> ```
> response-auth = "rspauth" "=" response-value
> ```
>
> where response-value is calculated as above, using the values sent
>   in    step two, except that if qop is "auth", then A2 is
>
> ```
>    A2 = { ":", digest-uri-value }
> ```

Based on this, this is how i build my `rspauth`:

```
rspauth=b64enc(ByteConv('rspauth=:'+md5_this("xmpp/example.com")))
```

Which boils down to:

```
# md5_this == 6dae15e9021a0103e8e09ce86956a659 (obv not with example.com)
respauth = 'cnNwYXV0aD02ZGFlMTVlOTAyMWEwMTAzZThlMDljZTg2OTU2YTY1OQ=='
cli.respond('<challenge xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>cnNwYXV0aD02ZGFlMTVlOTAyMWEwMTAzZThlMDljZTg2OTU2YTY1OQ==</challenge>')
```

According to [this thread](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-server/issues/12) on the matter, the last thing i send is wrong, I should be sending:

```
<success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>cnNwYXV0aD02ZGFlMTVlOTAyMWEwMTAzZThlMDljZTg2OTU2YTY1OQ==</success>
```

This fails as well and then the client sends `</stream:stream>` and the connection breaks.
With the `<challenge>...`


Now this is where I'm lost, I'm assuming I'm building the `rspauth=...` token wrong, but I don't know what it's supposed to be.

Here's the full communication trace between `Pidgin` and the XMPP server:

```
client connected
<< <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<< <stream:stream to='example.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>

>> Sending: <?xml version='1.0'?>
                <stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='example.com' id='d86961dc-bfb5-4578-aa45-116d5f14ef54' xml:lang='en' xmlns='jabber:client'>
                    <stream:features>
                        <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'><required/></starttls>
                        <register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>

<< <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
>> Sending: <proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
 - Secure connection established [TLS]

<< <stream:stream to='example.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
>> sending: <?xml version='1.0'?>
                <stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='example.com' id='516f7395-4112-4892-87f1-2e9f7f3a96e1' xml:lang='en' xmlns='jabber:client'>
                    <stream:features>
                        <mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
                            <mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism>
                        </mechanisms>
                    <auth xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth'/>
                </stream:features>

<< <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='DIGEST-MD5' xmlns:ga='http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth' ga:client-uses-full-bind-result='true'/>
>> Sending: <challenge xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>cmVhbG09ImV4YW1wbGUuY29tIixub25jZT0iMTE2Iixxb3A9ImF1dGgiLGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTgsYWxnb3JpdGhtPW1kNS1zZXNz</challenge>

<< <response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>dXNlcm5hbWU9InRvcnhlZCIscmVhbG09ImV4YW1wbGUuY29tIixub25jZT0iMTE2Iixjbm9uY2U9IjZGUDF5RUtBRk1TN2lHSnRBNlNiME5oQ1JBcmhGU0t3OHRMa2xJVEJPZGs9IixuYz0wMDAwMDAwMSxxb3A9YXV0aCxkaWdlc3QtdXJpPSJ4bXBwL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tIixyZXNwb25zZT1jODhmNTRiMjJlMmFiZGI4ZThlMTljOWVjZDliYjAxOCxjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04</response> 
>> Sending: <challenge xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>cnNwYXV0aD1lYTQwZjYwMzM1YzQyN2I1NTI3Yjg0ZGJhYmNkZmZmZA==</challenge>
   DEBUG: rspauth=ea40f60335c427b5527b84dbabcdfffd

<< </stream:stream>
```

I've followed these RFC guides:

- http://www.xmpp.org/internet-drafts/draft-saintandre-rfc3920bis-01.html
- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2831.txt
- http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SASLandDIGEST-MD5

And had a look at these source codes:

- https://github.com/jaxl/JAXL/blob/master/xmpp/xmpp.auth.php#L86 (also checked this out)
- https://github.com/thobbs/pure-sasl/blob/1f7428b8ed37e5ab6d5500b53a637c4698a298ad/puresasl/mechanisms.py

And basically what's left is to reverse engineer a successful connection and break down the responses even further, but the md5 hashes is tricky to reverse in a timely manner, so I'm asking for help this time.

### Found something

Checked around in some old source codes and found the following:

```
respauth = step_4 + ':' + nonce + ':' + cresp['nc'] + ':' + cnonce + ':' + cresp['qop'] + ':' + step_5
rspauth = 'rspauth=' + md5_this(rspauth)
```

Now It still generates the same error, but it's something other than static strings so I got that to work with for now.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is 4 months old, but i had exact same problem, and i seem to have solved it.

the rfc for sasl digest (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2831#section-2.1.3)

i made the code in C#, but it should be easy to adept, i used the Function names as they use in the RFC.

i know the code is not feature complete or bug free, but this works for me in pidgin, gajim and psi (psi does not check the returning hash from server, i am sure that is concerning). i hope this code helps you, or others that needed to look this up.

**!ATTENTION! MD5-Digest is seen as unsafe, and the new standart is SCRAM SASL (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802)**

The methode to Check the client Hash

```
public string GenerateClientHash(string user, string realm, string password, string nonce, string cnonce, string authzid, string digesturi, string qop, string nc)
            {
                byte[] A2 = (qop.Equals("auth") ? Encoder.GetBytes($"AUTHENTICATE:{digesturi}"): Encoder.GetBytes($"AUTHENTICATE:{digesturi}:00000000000000000000000000000000"));
    
                byte[] h1 = H(Encoder.GetBytes($"{user}:{realm}:{password}"));
                byte[] h2 = Encoder.GetBytes($":{nonce}:{cnonce}");
    
                byte[] A1 = Merge(h1,h2);
                byte[] response_value = HEX(KD(HEX(H(A1)),
                    Merge(Encoder.GetBytes($"{nonce}:{nc}:{cnonce}:{qop}:"), HEX(H(A2)))
                    ));
    
                byte[] h3 = Merge(h1, h2);
                return Encoder.GetString(response_value);
            }
```

Generate Server Hash (the one you had problems with)

```
public string GenerateServerHash(string user, string realm, string password, string nonce, string cnonce, string authzid, string digesturi, string qop, string nc)
        {
            byte[] A2 = (qop.Equals("auth") ? Encoder.GetBytes($":{digesturi}") : Encoder.GetBytes($":{digesturi}:00000000000000000000000000000000"));

            byte[] h1 = H(Encoder.GetBytes($"{user}:{realm}:{password}"));
            byte[] h2 = Encoder.GetBytes($":{nonce}:{cnonce}");

            byte[] A1 = Merge(h1, h2);
            byte[] response_value = HEX(KD(HEX(H(A1)),
                Merge(Encoder.GetBytes($"{nonce}:{nc}:{cnonce}:{qop}:"), HEX(H(A2)))
                ));

            byte[] h3 = Merge(h1, h2);
            return Encoder.GetString(response_value);
        }
```

The functions that the RFC mentioned.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Let H(s) be the 16 octet MD5 hash [RFC 1321] of the octet string s.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">Byte Array Af streng for at sikre encodning</param>
        /// <returns>s -> Base16(s) = s16 -> MD5Hash(s16)</returns>
        public byte[] H(byte[] s)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            return md5.ComputeHash(s);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Let KD(k, s) be H({k, ":", s}), i.e., the 16 octet hash of the string k, a colon and the string s.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="k">Byte Array Af streng for at sikre encodning</param>
        /// <param name="s">Byte Array Af streng for at sikre encodning</param>
        /// <returns>k + ":" + s = ks -> H(ks)</returns>
        public byte[] KD(byte[] k, byte[] s)
        {
            byte[] colon = Encoder.GetBytes(":");
            byte[] ks = Merge(k, colon, s);
            return H(ks);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Let HEX(n) be the representation of the 16 octet MD5 hash n as a string of 32 hex digits(with alphabetic characters always in lower case, since MD5 is case sensitive).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="n">Byte Array Af streng for at sikre encodning</param>
        /// <returns>lowercase of n</returns>
        public byte[] HEX(byte[] n)
        {
            byte[] b = Encoder.GetBytes(toBase16(n).ToLower());
            return b;
        }
```

Comment: I would have to verify this some how and pick up where I left off. But I'm thankful for your answer no matter how long it's been since I asked the question : )